# how do I start gnome-session over VNC (server OS: debian bookworm)?

Tags: debian, vnc, tightvnc

Using tightvncserver, how do I load gnome-session over a VNC session? tried editing ~/.vnc/xstartup with

```
gnome-session &
```

but the screen stays gray.

---

What I tried:

```
unset SESSION_MANAGER
exec /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc
export $(dbus-launch)
gnome-session &
```

---

If I try

```
startxfce4 &
```

without specifying anything else I have no issues and I can use the system, however I don't like the look of default xfce and would prefer gnome.

OS: debian bookworm, default gnome version (43), tightvncserver

Comment: Try comment out the: "exec /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc".   The command exec is like "run the /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc and ignore all the following lines"